# distance between irreducible elements in a number ring

Tags: number-theory

Consider the number ring $\mathbb{Z}[\phi]$ where $\phi$ is the positive root of $X^2-X-1$.
Any of its elements can be written as $a+b\phi$ with $a$ and $b$ integers. There is a norm $N$ such that $N(a+b\phi)=|a^2+ab-b^2|$. The norm is multiplicative and satisfies $N(\phi)=1$.

Let $p$ be a prime number greater than 5, which is a square mod 5. A consequence of Dirichlet's unit theorem is that there are two elements x and y such that the elements whose norm is $p$ are those of the form $\pm x \phi^k$ or $\pm y \phi^k$, with $k$ an integer. For instance, with $p=11$, one may generate the set of elements of norm 11 with $3+\phi$ or $4-\phi$ (we just have to check that these values are not the same up to a power of $\phi$). More generally, it is always possible to find such $x$ and $y$, positives, with the additional property that $xy=p$.

Since from the point of view of the norm, the elements $x$ and $x\phi$ are the same, it is quite natural to consider the elements $\log_{\phi}x \mod 1$ and $\log_{\phi}y \mod 1$ on the unit circle. So here comes my question : is it true that, taking all $p$ primes>5 that are squares mod 5, the set of distance between those values is dense in ]0,1/2[? Thanks by advance for any hint or comment.

Comment: Which is it? Primes > 5 or squares mod 5? Or both?

Comment: both of them. Density of all squares mod 5 is trivial. For primes that are not squares mod 5, like 2 or 3, there is no element having this prime as a norm

Answer (score 1):

Call $g(x)=\log_\phi x$ and $f(x)=g(x)\bmod1$ and let $S=\{n\in\Bbb P:(\frac n5)=1\}$ be the set whose image we want to prove dense. It follows from the density of $f(S)$ on $[0,1]$ that $d(f(S),f(S))$ is dense in $[0,\frac12]$ (just pick one element to be fixed and consider its distance to every other element). The density of $f(S)$ follows from:

- $g$ is monotone increasing
- $g$ is unbounded
- Differences between adjacent elements of $g(S)$ tends to zero.

Only the last is in question. Since the primes are equidistributed across different remainder classes ([Chebotarev's density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem)), gaps in $S$ carry the same asymptotic properties as the prime gaps themselves. From the prime number theorem, the quotient $g_n/p_n\to0$, where $g_n$ is the $n$-th prime gap; the same can be said about $S$, so $\frac{S_{n+1}-S_n}{S_n}\to0\implies\log_\phi S_{n+1}-\log_\phi S_n\to0$, and hence the difference of log primes goes to 0.

Comment: thanks for your help but I don't get the point. I am considering only primes, hence a subset of the set T

Comment: I see. Your original statement confused me, regarding what exactly you are considering to be your $S$. Is it the set of primes that are squares mod $5$, or all primes?

Comment: the question is not interesting for primes that are not squares mod 5, because you cannot find any element in the number ring having this prime as a norm then.

Comment: @Fractality Does the edit address your concerns?

Comment: well if I am not misunderstanding what you have written, your result is related to gaps of primes. This is not the same framework here, because for a given prime, two elements may be associated and I would like to gather informations on their difference. As you mention it (and I did not !), if the case of density is solved, it would be very interesting to investigate the distribution of those differences.

Comment: @Fractality I'm sorry, but I'm really having a hard time understanding what you are after. What do you mean "two elements may be associated"? What I wrote above shows that the logarithms of primes which are quadratic residues mod 5 (or indeed, in any nontrivial set of conjugacy classes) are dense in $[0,1]$. Is there some additional restriction I am missing?

Comment: The distribution of the differences will be similar to the distribution of prime gaps, which have been [the subject of intense study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap), involving such conjectures as Riemann's hypothesis. As such, I don't think you'll get much more mileage than what is already here before you reach an open problem.

Comment: Please consider the case of the example of the prime 11. Following what I have written, all numbers of norm 11 may be obtained with $3+\phi$ and $4-\phi$. The elements x and y are approximately 0.1794... and 0.8036..., so on the unit circle their difference is approx. 0.3757... . Do the same for all other primes ending with 1 or 9 and guess where the values of those differences are. This has nothing to do with the difference between two consecutive primes.

Comment: For norm 19 : all elements may be generated with $5-\phi$ and $4+\phi$. The $\log_{\phi}$ of those values on the unit circle are approx. 0.53206... and 0.58674... and the difference is 0.05468..., and so on...

Comment: And what set do you want to be dense then?

Comment: the set of differences between the two values that represent where the generators of elements of norm p are up to a power of $\phi$

Comment: How many generators are there for $p=11$? Are you only considering the two you mention ($3+\phi$ and $4-\phi$) or the differences between every pair of generators?

Comment: Ah, hm well, I see your problem now, and I'm sorry but I got no solution for you. On the bright side, my proof shows that the *sum* of your pair of generators on the unit circle are dense, but I can't say anything about the differences.